# Bad performance while converting pdf to Bitmap [.png] using Pdf2Image

Tags: c#, bitmapimage

let me explain you suppose my uploaded pdf has 20 page then we convert  pdf into single pages and then convert into .png. so it takes too much time. right now for 20 page this code take 2 minutes

```
string result = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/TempSplitPDF")) + "/result";
for (int j = 1; j <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; j++)
{                   
    Bitmap imagelst = new Pdf2Image(result + j + ".pdf").GetImage();
}                                                                        
imageModal = new ImageModel();                                
imageModal.FileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".png";
```

Any one help me please!

Comment: This is far too vague. Please add more detail about what you consider "bad performance".

Comment: Also what does this have to do with MVC?

Comment: @MattJones - yes this code in MVC ,Bitmap imagelst = new Pdf2Image(result + j + ".pdf").GetImage();  this line is taking time for converting pdf to imgae. let me explain you suppose my uploaded pdf has 20 page then we convert into  this pdf into single page and then convert into .png. so it takes too much time. right now for 20 page this code take 2 minutes.

Comment: Please add this to the **question** - useful information in comments is very annoying. Also, why aren't you doing anything with your `Bitmap`? You throw it away each time.

Comment: @JimYarbro - yes this is in MVC.

Comment: Why are you splitting the PDF into single pages? Why are you not using the `GetImages()` method to get an array of all the pages converted to images? Your code makes no sense.

Comment: @MattJones -because I need this functionality. like when choose one file for upload after that I also give Arrange, Rotate  Pages  functionality. so I need to split it and for you information I already use GetImages() this method.please see code carefully.

Comment: @The_Outsider -have you any idea about this.

Comment: @MattJones -- see below is my answer and don't tell me my code makes no sense.

Comment: I will tell you my opinion of your code - if you don't want people commenting on your code, don't put it on the internet.

Comment: @MattJones then give your opinion in proper way/proper language, don't use such language/word like 'Your code makes no sense. !!'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is working for me with very fast performance.

```
GhostscriptPngDevice dev = new GhostscriptPngDevice(GhostscriptPngDeviceType.Png256);
dev.GraphicsAlphaBits = GhostscriptImageDeviceAlphaBits.V_4;
dev.TextAlphaBits = GhostscriptImageDeviceAlphaBits.V_4;
dev.ResolutionXY = new GhostscriptImageDeviceResolution(290, 290);
dev.InputFiles.Add(result + j + ".pdf");
dev.Pdf.FirstPage = 1;
dev.Pdf.LastPage = 1;
dev.PostScript = string.Empty;
dev.OutputPath = Server.MapPath(@"~/TempPDF" + "\\" + imageModal.FileName);
dev.Process();
```